# Get Facebook Message via Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way to get Messages from my private Inbox in Facebook via Api? I dont find anything in the current api documentation ;(

I would bei very gratefull for every hint. Tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot access your privat inbox with the API anymore. It is only possible to access Page conversations (of course, if you manage the Page): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations/